# Unable to run Today extension widget( iOS 8) in simulator

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I made a simple Today extension widget in Xcode 6 beta and trying to run it in simulator. But while run it, its showing a popup list to choose an app from the list and i can not see the Today app in the list. Anyone help me please what i am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Here is the screenshot: [image]

Comment: For some reason you aren't getting the choice of "Today" as an application to run the extension in. Make sure you are using Xcode 6 Beta 2.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the current beta rather than you doing something wrong. In my case, I can only see the Today app when running on a device – in the simulator, you have to run the app and start the widget manually. Several people I've spoken to confirm the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you need to run the containing app rather than the extension target, so you would run MyTest rather than MyToday in your case. Once your app is running, you can open the Today view of notification center by pulling down from the top of the screen. Tap the bottom Edit button, and you should see your app extension in the list to add to the Today view.

As of Beta 2, app extensions are still somewhat buggy, so you may have to repeatedly clean and build your app and restart the iOS Simulator in order for your extension to be installed correctly and to reflect your latest changes.

Comment: did they fix it in beta 6? as I'm facing the same in beta 6

Answer (score 0):

It has already been pointed out that the current beta is very buggy when it comes to extensions. I have to press the run button multiple times to see my today widget extension. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I wasn't able to figure out a pattern.

In fact, if you watch the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#205) (about 20 minutes in) you notice that the demo fails the first time too. The second try works (for no obvious reason).

Answer (score 0):

On very first time
-Run app target instead of Widget Target 
If You have made any changes then
-Delete app from simulator and Run again

Answer (score 0):

If your developer profile is correct, fix issue is done with success, your app can be successfully installed in the simulator or device with no problem try this solution:

go to the top screen and click to the name of your extension: in this case MyToday .

So then click on -> Edit scheme (then, in the bottom of the screen) -> Manage Schemes, so select your extension and remove it with the - button in the left bottom of the window.

After that make sure the Autocreate schemes flag is selected to the top of the window, then press "Autocreate Schemes Now". After that another scheme MyToday appear at the bottom of the other schemes, this time with the correct Today Extension Run App.